How to upload files to subfolders for sharepoint but have no right to the home page with CSOM for c#
I upload a excel file to the subfolder of the sharepoint, my account can access the subfolder:
https://inteltechcorp.sharepoint.com/sites/inteltechShared/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fsites%2FOEM%2Dinteltech%2DFabrinetShared%2FShared%20Documents%2Finteltech%20%2D%20OEM%20Transfer%20Project%2FBC%20Kitting%20%2D%20Mirror%20from%20Fileshare
But I have no right to the home page: https://inteltechcorp.sharepoint.com/sites/inteltechShared.
I use the CSOM library of C# to upload the files,
the error message from my project:
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequestException: 'Cannot contact site at the specified URL:https://inteltechcorp.sharepoint.com/sites/inteltechShared/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fsites%2FOEM%2Dinteltech%2DFabrinetShared%2FShared%20Documents%2Finteltech%20%2D%20OEM%20Transfer%20Project%2FBC%20Kitting%20%2D%20Mirror%20from%20Fileshare
how can I upload the file to sharepoint? can you help me to solve it? thanks very much.
            siteUrl="https://inteltechcorp.sharepoint.com/sites/inteltechShared/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fsites%2FOEM%2Dinteltech%2DFabrinetShared%2FShared%20Documents%2Finteltech%20%2D%20OEM%20Transfer%20Project%2FBC%20Kitting%20%2D%20Mirror%20from%20Fileshare"

string documentLibraryName = "Documents";
using (var context = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
    context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, GetSecureString(password));
    List documentLibrary = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(documentLibraryName);
    context.Load(documentLibrary);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}


  string siteUrl = "Your_Site_URL";
    string username = "Your_Username";
    string password = "Your_Password";
    string subfolderUrl = "Subfolder_Relative_URL"; // Relative URL of the subfolder within the site

    // ClientContext
    using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
    {
        // Credentials
        context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, GetSecureString(password));

        // Get the subfolder
        Folder subfolder = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(subfolderUrl);
        context.Load(subfolder);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
}

